# Easy example for commutative ring with prime characteristics that has two different roots for $f=x^p-a$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

The question given was to find an example of ring with prime characteristics such that its two different roots of $f=X^p-a$ both have multiplicity p. I can only think of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. The main takeaway for this problem is to show that for some cases of the ring with prime characteristics, sum of multiplicities of roots can exceed the degree of f.

Comment: Hint: The ring cannot be an integral domain for over an integral domain the degree of the polynomial gives an upper bound to the number of zeros (counted with multiplicity). So you need the ring to either be non-commutative or to have zero divisors. A suitable matrix ring or a suitable quotient ring of the polynomial ring will do nicely.

Comment: I get the idea why integral domain will not work... Matrix or quotient ring that has prime p characteristics looks still challenging. Thank you very much though